# Shadow any2stringadd when implicitly converting Symbol

Tags: scala, implicits

I am trying to implicitly add functions to the `Symbol` class through two levels of implicits (as described [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/chaining-implicits.html)).
Consider the following code:

```
case class A(s: Symbol)
case class B(s: A) {
  def +[X](s: X)(implicit xtoa: X=>A) = B(xtoa(s))
}
implicit def xToB[X](s: X)(implicit xtoa: X => A) = B(xtoa(s))
implicit def symbolToA(s: Symbol) = A(s)

val x = 'a + 'b
```

This program does not compile:

> Error: value + is not a member of Symbol

It seems that the problem is that instead of picking the implicits defined in the snipped, scala converts `'a` with the `any2stringadd` function. In fact, the following two experiments seem to make the code compile:

- I can use a different function name instead of `+` (like `add` for instance)
- I can explicitly shadow `any2stringadd` in the imports: `import Predef.{any2stringadd => _ , _}`

I don't like either solution. My question is, is there any other way to rephrase my program to convince scala to select my implicits instead?

NB.: I'm using scala 2.12.1. Interestingly, IntelliJ does not complain about this snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bring another thing named any2stringadd into scope.

```
object myDsl {
  object any2stringadd

  case class A(s: Symbol)
  case class B(s: A) {
    def +[X](s: X)(implicit xtoa: X=>A) = B(xtoa(s))
  }
  implicit def xToB[X](s: X)(implicit xtoa: X => A) = B(xtoa(s))
  implicit def symbolToA(s: Symbol) = A(s)
}

import myDsl._
val x = 'a + 'b
```